# Regex error with \S in Scala: scala.StringContext$InvalidEscapeException: invalid escape '\S'

Tags: scala

I'm trying to collect only domains from List of urls with this regex:

```
val regDomains = s"""(?im)^http[s]*://[^/]+/(?!\S)""".r
```

In the docs http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/util/matching/Regex.html
there is a statement:

> using triple quotes avoids having to escape the backslash character

but I got exception

> scala.StringContext$InvalidEscapeException: invalid escape '\S' not
>   one of [\b, \t, \n, \f, \r, \, \", \']

whenever I try to run my program. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use string interpolation `s"""..."""`, doing so breaks the regex:

```
scala> val myRegex = """\S""".r
myRegex: scala.util.matching.Regex = \S

scala> myRegex.findAllIn("a b c 1 2 3").toList
res0: List[String] = List(a, b, c, 1, 2, 3)

scala> val myRegex = s"""\S""".r
scala.StringContext$InvalidEscapeException: invalid escape '\S' not one of [\b, \t, \n, \f, \r, \\, \", \'] at index 0 in "\S". Use \\ for literal \.
```

Comment: You can use the `raw` interpolator if you still want to use interpolation.  `val myRegex = raw """\S""".r`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to insert variable info, then the raw interpolator is useful:

```
raw"""(?im)^http[s]*://[^/]+/(?!\S)$myVar""".r
```